# Angular HTTP request delay interceptor not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, delay

I wanted to use an HTTP interceptor so that every HTTP request has a delay of 500ms between the next one. I'm currently making these requests from an injectable service that is registered on the app.module and injected in my component. In the that same module I have registered my interceptor.

*// delay-interceptor.ts*

```js
@Injectable()
export class DelayInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return timer(500).pipe(
            delay(500),            
            switchMap(() => next.handle(request))
        )
    }
}
```

*// app.module.ts*

```js
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: DelayInterceptor,
        multi: true
    },
    ManageHousesService
]
```

*// manage-houses.component.ts*

```js
createHouses() {

    this.houses.foreach((house: House) => {

        this.createHousesService.createHouse(house.name).subscribe(createdHouse => {

            house.rooms.foreach((room: Room) => {

                this.createHousesService.createRoom(house.id, room.name).subscribe();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

*// manage-houses.service.ts*

```js
createHouse(houseName: string): Observable<House> {

    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiUrl}/houses`, { houseName: houseName });
}

createRoom(houseId: string, roomName: string): Observable<Room> {

    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiUrl}/houses/${houseId}/rooms`, { roomName: roomName });
}
```

In my component I have to make requests in a nested way. I have a list of houses and for each house I want to create a list of rooms. So for each house I make a POST request and on the subscription I use the ID of the newly created house to create the rooms. For each room I make a POST request with the room information and the house ID. Now this is where the issue appears. Between each house request the delay is working, but between all the rooms of a house it is not, and I can't figure out why that's happening.

I suppose it might have something to do with calling the same method inside each foreach which will probably reuse the same observable or something similar, and thus not trigger the HTTP interceptor, but I'm not sure. On the interceptor I tried to use both the timer and the delay approach, but I got the same result with both approaches.

Comment: This interceptor doesn't separate your requests by 500ms, instead it delay it in 500ms, it's different behaviors.

Comment: Ah, I see, I suppose that makes sense. Is it possible to separate requests by a given time amount with an interceptor?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you need to use the interceptor to create a queue and fire one request of the queue every 500ms. I'm on mobile now, but as soon as possible I write an answer elaborating this idea.

Comment: I think you should try another solution for these nested way you made requests with try to use something like `forkjoin` or `zip` to accomplish the same result in a more reactive approach

Answer (score 1):

how do you suppose that each request will take maximum 500ms?
it may take longer than that

did you try to use `async/await`?

you can use `await` to handle this asynchronous code, also it's better to avoid using `forEach` in asynchronous code, as `forEach` is not a promise-aware, that's how it has been designed
so it's better to the use the normal `for loop` or the ES6 `for of loop`

also we need to git rid of the subscribe and unsubscribe as now by using the `async/await`, we need to deal with `promises` instead of `observables`

for that, `RxJS` provides the `toPromise()` operator which converts an `Observable` to a `promise` so you can work with the `HttpClient` methods using `promises` instead of `Observables`

`toPromise()` returns a `Promise` that is resolved with the first value emitted by that `Observable` (it internally calls `subscribe` for you and wraps it with a `Promise` object).

you can then update the `createHouses` function to be something like that

```
async createHouses() {

    for (const house of this.houses) {
        // wait for the house to be added to db
        await this.createHousesService.createHouse(house.name).toPromise();

        // then loop over the rooms
        for (const room of house.rooms) {
            // wait for the room to be added to the db
            await this.createHousesService.createRoom(house.id, room.name).toPromise()
        }
    }
}
```

hope it works as you needed

Answer (score 0):

It is not correctly to change the behavior of the interceptor, because it will affect all requests. You can do this directly from the component, or create a service for this prototype.

```
concat(
  ...this.houses.map((house: House) =>
    this.createHousesService.createHouse(house.name).pipe(
      delay(500),
      concatMap((createdHouse) =>
        concat(
          ...house.rooms.map((room: Room) =>
            this.createHousesService
              .createRoom(house.id, room.name)
              .pipe(delay(500))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
).subscribe();
```